# Can I use VBScript to take existing CSVs and make them tabs of a single Excel Workbook?

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript, scripting, automation

I'm attempting to automate a process in which I take multiple CSVs from a directory and make them each their own tab in an Excel workbook so I can pivot off their data and such. I'm trying to avoid using macros if possible... Is it possible to do this in VBScript?
Here is what I have tried so far, please excuse my programming conventions as I've only just recently learned the basics of VBS:

```
Call createWkbk()

Function createWkbk()
strFileName = "c:\test1.xls"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()

'Adds one spreadsheet to book for each command
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

'This renames all the sheets to 'int#'
objExcel.Sheets(1).Name = "int1"
objExcel.Sheets(2).Name = "int2"
objExcel.Sheets(3).Name = "int3"
objExcel.Sheets(4).Name = "int4"
objExcel.Sheets(5).Name = "int5"
objExcel.Sheets(6).Name = "int6"

'To save the book
objWorkbook.SaveAs(strFileName)

objExcel.Quit
End Function
```

So now the only thing I need to do is write those CSVs I already have into those sheets, or import them from the very beginning. If not in VBScript, what is the suggested route to take?

Thank you all in advance,

Nic

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `QueryTable` to quickly import a CSV into an existing worksheet:

```
Const strFile = "c:\test.csv"
Const strSheet = "Sheet1"

Set Sheet = objExcel.Sheets(strSheet)

With Sheet.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" & strFile, Sheet.Range("A1"))
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .Refresh
End With
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this also, A code that I found and adapt for my use :

```
Sub ImportXlsSheets()

'On crée une variable 'wbFusion' de type Classeur Excel
Dim wbFusion As Workbook
'On l'associe au classeur à partir duquel tu lances la macro
Set wbFusion = ThisWorkbook

'On crée une variable wbCible qui va correspondre tour à tour aux classeur à importer
Dim wbCible As Workbook
Dim shCible As Worksheet

'Afin de lui affecter des fichiers, l'utilisateur va les sélectionner via une boîte de dialogue
'NOTA : le With XXXXXXXXX évite de répéter plein de fois XXXXXXXXX lorsque l'on parle de la même chose ;)
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Title = "Choisissez le(s) classeur(s) à importer"
    .Filters.Add "Classeur Excel", "*.xls,*.xls?" 'on filtre par tous les fichiers .xls et xls? avec '?' signifiant "1 caractère"
    .ButtonName = "Importer ce(s) classeur(s)"
    .AllowMultiSelect = True 'on autorise la sélection multiple
    .Show 'on affiche la fenêtre, on attend le retour de l'utilisateur pour continuer

    'on a réglé la boîte de dialogue, maintenant il faut traiter les données de l'utilisateur :
    'si l'utilisateur n'a pas sélectionné de fichier, on met un message d'erreur
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Veuillez sélectionner au moins un fichier", vbExclamation, "Erreur"
    'Sinon, on traite :
    Else
        For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            'On ouvre chaque classeur un par un
            Set wbCible = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(i))
            CouleurOnglet = RGB(Rnd * 255, Rnd * 255, Rnd * 255) 'on va mettre toutes les pages de ce classeur importées avec l'onglet de la même couleur
            CompteurClasseur = CompteurClasseur + 1 'on incrémente un compteur, facultatif
            'Pour chaque feuille du wbCible :
            For Each shCible In wbCible.Sheets
                shCible.Tab.Color = CouleurOnglet
                'shCible.Name = Int(Rnd * 99999) 'nom aléatoire pour être certain qu'il n'y ait pas de doublon plantant la macro
                shCible.Name = i & "_" & shCible.Name ' To keep the original sheet name and concatenate it with its order
                shCible.Copy after:=wbFusion.Sheets(wbFusion.Sheets.Count) 'on la copie à la fin de wbFusion
                CompteurFeuille = CompteurFeuille + 1 'on incrémente un compteur, facultatif
            Next shCible
            'On ferme le classeur sans enregistrer (on a changé le nom des pages avant copie)
            wbCible.Close SaveChanges:=False
        'On passe au classeur suivant
        Next i
        'Facultatif, à l'aide des compteurs, on indique à l'utilisateur que tout s'est bien passé
        MsgBox CompteurFeuille & " feuilles ont bien été importées, provenant de " & CompteurClasseur & " classeurs Excel.", vbInformation, "Import réussi"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation? Comments in french are not helpful for everyone. Seems that your code has filter for *.xls, *.xlsm (or other char than m) so it's not suitable for csv files